# Como retirar obrigatoriedade de upload de imagem?

Tags: php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
   $("#date").mask("99/99/9999",{placeholder:"dd/mm/yyyy"});
});
</script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="main-inner">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">

            <div class="span12">                
                <div id="target-1" class="widget">   

                <div class="widget-header">
                        <i class="icon-file"></i>
                        <h3>Cadastrar Postagem</h3>
                    </div> <!-- /widget-header -->

                    <div class="widget-content">                        

                        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['cadastrar'])){
            $titulo         = trim(strip_tags($_POST['titulo']));
            $data           = trim(strip_tags($_POST['data']));
            $exibir         = trim(strip_tags($_POST['exibir']));
            $descricao      = $_POST['descricao'];




            //INFO IMAGEM
        $file       = $_FILES['img'];
        $numFile    = count(array_filter($file['name']));

        //PASTA
        $folder     = '../upload/postagens/';

        //REQUISITOS
        $permite    = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png');
        $maxSize    = 1024 * 1024 * 5;

        //MENSAGENS
        $msg        = array();
        $errorMsg   = array(
            1 => 'O arquivo no upload é maior do que o limite definido em upload_max_filesize no php.ini.',
            2 => 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho em MAX_FILE_SIZE que foi especificado no formulário HTML',
            3 => 'o upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente',
            4 => 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo'
        );

        if($numFile <= 0){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                        Selecione uma imagem e tente novamente!
                    </div>';
        }
        else if($numFile >=2){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                        Você ultrapassou o limite de upload. Selecione apenas uma foto e tente novamente!
                    </div>';
        }else{
            for($i = 0; $i < $numFile; $i++){
                $name   = $file['name'][$i];
                $type   = $file['type'][$i];
                $size   = $file['size'][$i];
                $error  = $file['error'][$i];
                $tmp    = $file['tmp_name'][$i];

                $extensao = @end(explode('.', $name));
                $novoNome = rand().".$extensao";

                if($error != 0)
                    echo $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> ".$errorMsg[$error];
                else if(!in_array($type, $permite))
                    echo $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem não suportada!";
                else if($size > $maxSize)
                    echo $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem ultrapassa o limite de 5MB";
                else{

                    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $folder.'/'.$novoNome)){
                        //$msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Upload Realizado com Sucesso!";

            $insert = "INSERT into tb_postagens (titulo, data, imagem, exibir, descricao) VALUES (:titulo, :data, :imagem, :exibir, :descricao)";

        try{
            $result = $conexao->prepare($insert);
            $result->bindParam(':titulo', $titulo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->bindParam(':data', $data, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->bindParam(':imagem', $novoNome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->bindParam(':exibir', $exibir, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->bindParam(':descricao', $descricao, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->execute();
            $contar = $result->rowCount();
            if($contar>0){
                echo '<div class="alert alert-success">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                      <strong>Sucesso!</strong> O post foi cadastrado.
                </div>';
            }else{
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                      <strong>Erro ao cadastrar!</strong> Não foi possível cadastrar o post.
                </div>';
            }           
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e;
        }   






                    }else
                        $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Desculpe! Ocorreu um erro...";

                }

                foreach($msg as $pop)
                echo '';
                    //echo $pop.'<br>';
            }
        }



        }


     ?>

                        <div class="tab-pane" id="formcontrols">
                                <form id="edit-profile" class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


                                        <div class="control-group">                                         
                                            <label class="control-label" for="username">Título da Postagem</label>
                                            <div class="controls">
                                                <input type="text" class="span6 disabled" id="titulo" value="" name="titulo">
                                            </div> <!-- /controls -->               
                                        </div> <!-- /control-group -->


                                        <div class="control-group">                                         
                                            <label class="control-label" for="firstname">Data</label>
                                            <div class="controls">
                                                <input type="text" class="span2" id="date" value="" name="data">
                                            </div> <!-- /controls -->               
                                        </div> <!-- /control-group -->


                                        <div class="control-group">                                         
                                            <label class="control-label" for="lastname">Imagem</label>
                                            <div class="controls">
                                                <input type="file" multiple class="span6 fileinput" id="imagem" name="img[]">
                                            </div> <!-- /controls -->               
                                        </div> <!-- /control-group -->


                                        <div class="control-group">                                         
                                            <label class="control-label" for="username">Exibir</label>
                                            <div class="controls">
                                                <select class="span2" id="exibir"  name="exibir">
                                                    <option>Sim</option>
                                                    <option>Não</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div> <!-- /controls -->               
                                        </div> <!-- /control-group -->


                                        <div class="control-group">                                         
                                            <label class="control-label" for="email">Descrição</label>
                                            <div class="controls">
                                                <textarea class="span8" name="descricao" id="descricao" value="" rows="10"></textarea>
                                            </div> <!-- /controls -->               
                                        </div> <!-- /control-group -->



                                        <div class="form-actions">
                                            <input type="submit" name="cadastrar" class="btn btn-primary" value="Salvar">
                                            <input type="reset" class="btn" value="Cancelar">
                                        </div> <!-- /form-actions -->
                                </form>



                    </div> <!-- /widget-content -->
                </div> <!-- /widget -->
            </div><!-- span 12 -->


    </div><!-- row -->        



        </div>
        <!-- /span6 --> 
      </div>
      <!-- /row --> 
    </div>
    <!-- /container --> 
  </div>
  <!-- /main-inner --> 
</div>
<!-- /main -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="editor/nicEdit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta remover a condição `$numFile <= 0`. Dessa forma você ignorará esse erro e poderá cadastrar uma postagem com ou sem, imagem.

```
if($numFile >=2){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                Você ultrapassou o limite de upload. Selecione apenas uma foto e tente novamente!
            </div>';
}else{
    for($i = 0; $i < $numFile; $i++){
        /* Restante do código */
    }
}
```

O problema é que você está verificando se o `upload` foi concluído com sucesso, caso tenha sido, cadastra a postagem. Nesse ponto você **deve** remover a parte do código que realiza o cadastro, de dentro da condicional `if (move_uploaded_file($tmp, $folder.$novoNome)) { ... }`

Outro ponto é que você permite o envio de múltiplas imagens, porém só utiliza uma dela. Seria legal refatorar essa parte, mas isso é outra questão.

**Segue código de exemplo:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['cadastrar'])){
    $titulo         = trim(strip_tags($_POST['titulo']));
    $data           = trim(strip_tags($_POST['data']));
    $exibir         = trim(strip_tags($_POST['exibir']));
    $descricao      = $_POST['descricao'];

    //INFO IMAGEM
    $file       = $_FILES['img'];
    $numFile    = count(array_filter($file['name']));

    //PASTA
    $folder     = '../upload/postagens/';

    //REQUISITOS
    $permite    = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png');
    $maxSize    = 1024 * 1024 * 5;

    //MENSAGENS
    $msg        = array();
    $errorMsg   = array(
        1 => 'O arquivo no upload é maior do que o limite definido em upload_max_filesize no php.ini.',
        2 => 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho em MAX_FILE_SIZE que foi especificado no formulário HTML',
        3 => 'o upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente',
        4 => 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo'
    );

    if($numFile >= 2 ){
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        Você ultrapassou o limite de upload. Selecione apenas uma foto e tente novamente!
        </div>';
    } else {

        $novoNome = "";

        for($i = 0; $i < $numFile; $i++){
            $name   = $file['name'][$i];
            $type   = $file['type'][$i];
            $size   = $file['size'][$i];
            $error  = $file['error'][$i];
            $tmp    = $file['tmp_name'][$i];

            $extensao = @end(explode('.', $name));
            $novoNome = rand().".$extensao";

            if($error != 0) {
                $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> ".$errorMsg[$error];
            }
            else if(!in_array($type, $permite)) {
                $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem não suportada!";
            }
            else if($size > $maxSize) {
                $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem ultrapassa o limite de 5MB";
            }
            else if(!move_uploaded_file($tmp, $folder.$novoNome)) {
                $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Imagem não cadastrada";
            }

            foreach($msg as $pop) {
                echo $pop;
            }
        }

        try{
            $result = $conexao->prepare($insert);
            $result->bindParam(':titulo', $titulo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->bindParam(':data', $data, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->bindParam(':imagem', $novoNome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->bindParam(':exibir', $exibir, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->bindParam(':descricao', $descricao, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->execute();
            $contar = $result->rowCount();

            if($contar > 0){
                echo '<div class="alert alert-success">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                <strong>Sucesso!</strong> O post foi cadastrado.
                </div>';
            } else {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                <strong>Erro ao cadastrar!</strong> Não foi possível cadastrar o post.
                </div>';
            }           
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die( $e->getMessage() );
        }
    }

}

?>
```